# Combining mixamo not in place animations

Tags: animation, mixamo

I tried to follow the steps from cgdive video and I managed to overcome the "teleportation (return) to the starting point between animations (transition), but the "sliding" effect still remained, can someone help me please.

Here is blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CVFH35UWB-SOSxF57uqoAFozTBcbH5oR/view?usp=sharing

His video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YK7sc7tovc0 (timecode:  47:07 - 52:53).

3d model animations (on same mixamo character): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PHQQTaKCckmgfIc0XwsP8FUWK15QUAJv/view?usp=drive_link https://drive.google.com/file/d/145gLzn8Y551fXvxx3qH_h2TS_GgS6p2o/view?usp=drive_link

Videos: https://watch.wave.video/tKf0qqefTwYvgZus https://watch.wave.video/X5tK7SxaRPj1o4kt

Comment: By the way I tried new pair of animations and transition between them doesn’t look good too.

Animations: https://files.fm/u/6nawddxkdg